# Kafka List all partition with no leader

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

In my kafka Cluster there are more than 2k topics and each topic has 5 partitions. I want list only that partitions which has no leader.

I can go can check for each topic using the below syntax:

```
kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic <topic_name> --zookeeper <zookeeper_ip>:port
```

But the problem is there are 2k+ topics, can't be done manually. I can also write a script to loop over each topic and get the partition with no leader. But i am interested in some efficient way to get the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `kafka-topics.sh` you can specify the `--unavailable-partitions` flag to only list partitions that currently don't have a leader and hence cannot be used by Consumers or Producers.

For example:

```
kafka-topics.sh --describe --unavailable-partitions --zookeeper <zookeeper_ip>:port
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the answer. I have seen that options in topics.sh but was not aware that i can do my job, thanks once agin for pointing it out.

Comment: I tried the above, but it listing everything one with no leader and also which has leader

Comment: What's your Kafka version? We're running on 2.0.0 and the above command works correctly for us, i.e. when we don't have `--unavailable-partitions` it lists every partition on the cluster, when we do have it it outputs nothing (as all our partitions are healthy).

Comment: kafka version is 1.1